# Copy an Excel range and paste as an image in a Picture Content Control inside a Word doc using VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, word-2010, vba

I'm trying to copy a range from Excel and paste it as an image into Word at the body of each page. I am using a Picture Content Control to achieve this. There seems to be limited documentation to use this control. Please help.

```
Dim objWord, objDoc As Object, rng As Range, objCC As ContentControl
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName).Names(strSheetName & "_Range").RefersToRange
rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Template.docx")
'Set objCC = objDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("idControl1")(1)
objDoc.PageSetup.Orientation = 1
objWord.Selection.Paste
objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
'objDoc.Save
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I tried using bookmarks and they work. Got the suggestion from http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=160430. I added this line to my code
    objWord.Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="bkm1".